# Trying to change an h1 tag based on the JQuery Attribute Contains

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link on a page that is generated dynamically and has an href that looks like `<a href="/ListJobs/ByCustom/Job-Category/Keyword-Accounting-Finance/">Accounting/Finance</a>` or `<a href="/ListJobs/ByCustom/StationLocation/Keyword-KCCI-TV/">KCCI-TV</a>`and I need to change an h1 tag based on either the Job-Category or StationLocation part of the link.  I have tried to use

```
if ($("table a[href='/ListJobs'][href='/ByCustom'][href='/StationLocation']")) {
            alert($('table a').attr("href"));
        } else {
            alert("Category");
            $('#mainbody h1').html("Careers by Category");
        }
```

as well as many of the other variations including

```
$("table a [href|='/ListJobs/ByCustom/Job-Category']
```

None of the efforts are having the desired result.  What should I be using to see if the href contains the part of the string that I need so I can change my h1 tag accordingly?

Comment: To locate the href, try var hrefVal = $("table").find("a").find("[href=/ListJobs]")

Comment: all of the links will start with the ListJobs, it is the StationLocation part that I need to know,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $("table a").each(function() {
if (this.href.indexOf('StationLocation') != -1) {
   alert($('table a').attr("href"));
} else {
    alert("Category");
        $('#mainbody h1').html("Careers by Category");
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the ^=   'starts with' operator?

```
if ($("table a[href^='/ListJobs'][href^='/ByCustom'][href^='/StationLocation']")) {
    alert($('table a').attr("href"));
} else {
    alert("Category");
    $('#mainbody h1').html("Careers by Category");
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: No luck, when I changed it and then selected to have the link generated with the jobs-category, I still got the alert with the link href attr, instead of the alert of Category like I want.  Any other thoughts?